# Visual Studio code - cannot connect to runtime process timeout after 10000 ms

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I was trying to launch the program from the debug console in VS Code but got the error on `cannot connect to runtime process timeout after 10000 ms`

launch.json

```
   "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "protocol": "inspector",
            "name": "Attach by Process ID",
            "processId": "${command:PickProcess}"
        },
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "protocol": "inspector",
            "name": "Attach",
            "port": 9229
        },
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "port":9230,
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\bin\\www"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to debug with VS Code but got hit by the error as below. Am I configuring my launch.json correctly ?

[image: Error Screenshot]

Comment: If the code has async/await functions, one should pass `--nolazy` flag to node process

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A "launch"-type configuration doesn't need to specify a port. When you set the `port` parameter, it assumes that your launch config will include the --inspect parameter with that port.

If you have to specify the exact port for some reason, then you can include the --inspect parameter like:

```
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "port":9230,
        "runtimeArgs": ["--inspect=9230"],
        "name": "Launch Program",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\bin\\www"
    }
```

But I recommend just removing "port" from your launch config.

Answer (score 7):

I'm using nodemon and babel to start visual studio code and found that you need to make sure you have a configuration in package.json and launch.json that are compatible with visual studio code.

Really, that means that you need to find a configuration that allows you to launch your regular configuration from powershell as well as gitbash in windows. Here's what I came up with:

In package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon --inspect --exec babel-node -- index.js",
  },
```

In launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [{
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch via Babel (works)",
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "port": 9229,
        "program": "",
        "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "runtimeArgs": [
            "start"
        ]
    }
    ]
}
```

When node starts you should see something like:

```
PS F:\noise\bookworm-api> cd 'F:\noise\bookworm-api'; & 'F:\applications\nodejs\npm.cmd' 'start'

> bookworm-api@1.0.0 start F:\noise\bookworm-api
> nodemon --inspect --exec babel-node -- index.js

[nodemon] 1.18.4
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `babel-node --inspect index.js`
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/e6e1ee3c-9b55-462e-b6db-4cf67221245e
For help see https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.
Running on localhost:3333
```

The thing you're really looking for is:

```
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/e6e1ee3c-9b55-462e-b6db-4cf67221245e
```

This output shows that your debugger is waiting on a WebSockets request on port 9229. You communicate that to visual studio code with:

```
"port": 9229,
```

In your launch.json file.

If you don't see the port that the debugging server is waiting on then you probably need to add the `--inspect` flag to your start command in node.

Comment: for inspector also you can add this part "protocol": "inspector", into the configurations directly. it has workout in my case

Answer (score 1):

I get this same error when I forget to close the browser from the last debug session. It holds on to the connection to the Angular proxy and prevents a new debug session from starting up. Once I close the browser, F5 starts up a new session without error.
[image: VS error message]

Answer (score 1):

1. duplicate `Google Chrome` shortcut → `itest`
2. **press** `alt` key **doubleclick** `itest`
3. **itest  Properties** → **Shortcut** → **Target** ：

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --remote-debugging-port=6062 --user-data-dir="%appdata%\Google\Chrome\itest`

4. VS Code, Menu **Debug** → **Add Configuration** → **Chrome: Attach** → `"port": 6062,` → `Ctrl+Shift+D` Debug → Switch **Attach to Chrome** → **Start Debugging**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Delete launch.json file and go to debug and create new launch.json file

Comment: working with python debugger, this solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

Open Android Studio, Configure, ADV Manager, create or open an ADV.
In VS Code and in debug click emulate android cordova

**Command line - cordova emulate android**

```
{
            "name": "cordova emulate android",
            "type": "cordova",
            "request": "launch",                                                                               
            "platform": "android",
            "target": "emulator",
            "port": 9222,           
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
           // "ionicLiveReload": true
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using docker-compose to run a react express app. You can see the full compose file below.

I got the mentioned error, and I added a port mapping as follows to resolve the issue.

```
  - "9229:9229"
```

Also the if you are using visual studio code, the address configuration in launch.json file inside of .vscode should be as follows.

```
"address": "0.0.0.0",
```

The full launch.json file is pasted below as well.

The full docker-compose.yml file looks as follows.

```
version: '3'
services:
  proxy:
    build:
      context: ./proxy 
    ports:
      - 7081:80

  redis-server:
    image: 'redis'

  node-app:
    restart: on-failure
    build: 
      context: ./globoappserver
    ports:
      - "9080:8080"
      - "9229:9229" ######### HERE IS THE FIX ##########
    container_name: api-server

  ui:
    build:
      context: ./globo-react-app-ui
    environment:
        - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true      
    ports:
      - "7000:3000"
    stdin_open: true 
    volumes:
      - ./globo-react-app-ui:/usr/app

  postgres:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./init-database.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-database.sql
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password

volumes:
  postgres:
```

Here is the launch.json file.

Take a look at this [reference](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387) for this file settings.

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "3",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Docker: Attach to Node",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach", // The other option is launch
            "port": 9229,
            //"address": "localhost",
            "address": "0.0.0.0",
            //"localRoot": "D:\\Vivek\\MxWork\\Js\\GloboClientServer\\src\\globoappserver",
            "localRoot": "D:/Vivek/MxWork/Js/GloboClientServer/src/globoappserver",
            "remoteRoot": "/app",
            "protocol": "inspector",
            "skipFiles": [
                //"<node_internals>/**",
                "<node_internals>/**/*.js",
                "${workspaceFolder}/**/node_modules/**/*.js"
            ]
            //"program": "${workspaceFolder}\\src\\globoappserver\\index.js"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Go to `Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General`
then disable
I'm using it successfully with the following options disabled.

In Visual Studio go to: `Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General`

Enable JavaScript debugging for Asp.Net (Chrome, Edge, and IE)
Enable Legacy Chrome JavaScript debugger for ASP.NET.

Comment: Hi teja teja, this question is about Visual Studio Code, not Visual Studio.

Answer (score -2):

In my case updating the core tools solved the issue.

Use the below command to update:

```
npm install -g azure-functions-core-tools
```